# how to implement stream readtimeout property

Tags: c#, .net, stream, httpwebresponse

I'm fixing a bug : the app will hang in download process for 5 minutes while losing network connection. What I need to do is reduce the hanging time to like 20 seconds.

log snippet:

```
Severe  2016-01-27 , 11:03:14
    在 HttpsDownload.doDownloadByHttps(FileDownloadInfo fileInfo, downloadingDelegate downDelegate)
    Message: Init method:GET

Info    2016-01-27 , 11:08:29
    在 HttpsDownload.writeToFile(FileDownloadInfo fileInfo, Stream stream, downloadingDelegate downDelegate, Boolean Clear)
    Message: Exception while reading from the response stream
    Exception:
        Message: time out
        Type: System.Net.WebException
           在 System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   在 HttpsDownload.writeToFile(FileDownloadInfo fileInfo, Stream stream, downloadingDelegate downDelegate, Boolean Clear)
```

code snippet:

```
private void doDownloadByHttps(FileDownloadInfo fileInfo, downloadingDelegate downDelegate)
        {
                //code
                webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
                responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
                writeToFile(fileInfo, responseStream, downDelegate, bClear);
        }
private void writeToFile(FileDownloadInfo fileInfo, Stream stream, downloadingDelegate downDelegate, bool Clear)
        {
                int count = stream.Read(readBuffer, 0, BlockSize);
                while (count > 0) 
                {
                    //code
                    count = stream.Read(readBuffer, 0, BlockSize);
                }
        }
```

I believe that timeout occurs in `stream.Read` according to the log. So the easiest way to do the trick should be `stream.ReadTimeout = 20000`, but obviously I can't set the `ReadTimeout` property.
Another way that  can think of is to write a class override ReadTimeout like:

```
public class MyStream : Stream {
//code
public override int ReadTimeout { get; set; }
//code
}
```

But it's not preferred. Any better way to fix the bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout needs to be set in the `webRequest` object, of type `HttpWebRequest`.

Check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.readwritetimeout(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @little.ming Marking my response as the answer is enough :)